# Find the area of the parallelograms generated by following vectors in $ R ^ 3 $: $\vec x_1 = (4,5,-6), \vec x_2 = (1,4,1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, area

I believe the answer is $ 3 \sqrt{118} $, but the answer is $ 2 \sqrt{1062} $.

I did it the following way

$A = \begin{bmatrix}i&j&k\\ 4&5&-6\\ 1&4&1\\ \end{bmatrix} = 29i -10j +11k$

$|A|= \sqrt{29^2+(-10)^2+11^2}$=$ 3 \sqrt {118} $

Where did I go wrong? or is the answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: I think what you have calculated is the area of a triangle. To get the area of the parallelogram you have to multiply your answer by 2. If you do that you will get $2\sqrt{1062}$.

Comment: But why? I did the other 2 items in this exercise in this way and the answer was giving the same result as the answer. If I do the triangle in this one, I will have to multiply the other two by 2 and then the other two items will be wrong.